# Karma unit testing - finding out which abstract class a component implements

Tags: unit-testing, angular, karma-runner

I'm quite new to AngularJS and Karma. Nevertheless I'm ordered to write meaningful unit tests. As we are asked to implement the classes `OnInit` and `OnDestroy` in each component we create, I wonder whether there is a way to check with Karma if a component actually implements them.

Has anybody got an idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to check for implementation, you will need to check if the component actually implements the methods that are required by these abstract classes.

If `DummyComponent` is a component which `implements OnInit, OnDestroy` with no other dependencies then:

```
describe( 'DummyComponent', () => {
    let component: DummyComponent;

    beforeEach( () => {
        TestBed.configureTestingModule( {
            declarations: [
                DummyComponent
            ],
            providers: [
                { provide: ComponentFixtureAutoDetect, useValue: true }
            ]
        } );
        component = TestBed.createComponent( DummyComponent ).componentInstance;

    } );

    it( 'should implement onInit and onDestroy', () => {
        expect( component.ngOnInit ).toBeDefined;
        expect( component.ngOnDestroy ).toBeDefined;
    } );
} );
```